# how to work with multiple database in a loop in R

Tags: r

I am looking for someone to help me with this:

I want to subset many dataframes by using a loop, something like this

```
for (i in seq_along(data_list)){ 
  i <- subset(i, ID %in% list_code)
}
```

Basically, I want to subset a dataframe "i" and replace that dataframe over the same dataframe, kind of update my dataframe.

`data_list` is the list of names for my dataframes. `list_code` is the list of conditions for my ID. i want only my dataframe where ID is between 1 to 10 for each of my dataframes.
thank you

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with `lapply` and `Filter`

```
out <- Filter(function(x) all(x$ID %in% list_code), list_data)
```

---

A reproducible example with `iris`

```
list_data <- list(head(iris), tail(iris))
Filter(function(x) all(x$Species == "setosa"), list_data)
```